# Rails 3.2 page caching incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, utf-8, rack

I have successfully cached the page. This page contains characters like ्िः but when we call cached page following error occurs

```
[2014-02-18 01:35:24] ERROR Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
        /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:72:in `block in service'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/response.rb:87:in `each'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/response.rb:87:in `each'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I tried webrik and thin. Both giving same error
I tried lots of different solutions but didn't worked for me.
What I tried:
Added below line in layout

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Added comment in controller
    # encoding: UTF-8
And tried some more solutions like this.please reply if you know the answer
Error on thin https://gist.github.com/sagarjunnarkar/9066264
Error on WEBrik https://gist.github.com/sagarjunnarkar/9066287